# ArcGIS Desktop vector symbol levels: why a maximum of 32 colors?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

At 10.8.1, when applying vector *Layer Properties > Symbology > Quantities > Graduated colors*, a maximum of 32 color levels are possible.  Why 32 and not some other number?  Is there something special or unique about 32?

[image]

Comment: check this article where we have the ability to change the maximum limit https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000003713

Comment: It's just the dropdown that only goes up to 32. You can type a larger number manually if you want to (up to 256).

Comment: My guess would be that a developer set this limit to 32. Developers sometimes tend to think in powers of two, and 32 = 2^5. 256 = 2^8. Technically there is no reason whatsoever to use 32, it might as well be set to 10 or 25 or 100.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible that the 32 limit possible exists as a limitation of the software being able to perform that statistical classification to more than 32 classes, or possibly because from a visual perspective, the differences in colours beyond 32 classes in not easily recognizable

But lets take a step back.

The actual question is 'Why is there a maximum of 32 classification classes available for a dataset'.

What the graduated classification does is breaks your data up into (max) 32 different 'groups/classes'. There are different statistical methods for doing these 'breaks'. (Natural Breaks, Quartiles, number of Standard Deviations etc). It depends on your data. (see here for some advanced reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification)

So the question you need to ask yourself is whether a statistical scenario exists where you need to group your data, based on the values, into more than 32 groups. The short answer is that - in statistics, and especially from a visualization perspective, distinguishing between 32 different statistical 'classes' probably doesn't offer much value when just looking at the raw data.

Reading between the lines, at a guess, I'm thinking you perhaps just want to style your raw data based on a graduated colour symbology.

In which case, maybe try using 'Categories > Unique Values' in the style editor and pick an appropriate colour ramp. (again, im reading between the lines here as to a potential underlying question).